# Linking a SQL Server with a liferay instance running in a docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, liferay

So as the title says, I'm trying to run liferay in side of a docker container. Then from there, connect to a database on an outside node.

I can successfully ping the server that the SQL Server is running on from inside the docker container, however, when I try to connect to the database through liferay's configuration interface, it simply says an connection could not be established, and the logs state that log in for the user failed.

If it's not possible, I understand, just trying to get a better idea of this little mess.

======================================================================

Just to note, I've been using [snasello's](https://github.com/snasello/docker-liferay-6.2) docker image for liferay, except taking out the preconfigured database to force liferay to go to the configuration page. I'm starting the container with

```
docker run --rm -it -i 8080:8080 {whatever the local name of the image is}
```

00:00:34,301 WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->21r35xoL]-HelperThread-#6][BasicResourcePool:1851] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3b17c58d -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (3). Last acquisition attempt exception:
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot open database "lportal" requested by the login. The login failed.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:603)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.(ConnectionJDBC2.java:345)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:211)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
00:00:34,301 WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->21r35xoL]-HelperThread-#6][BasicResourcePool:894] Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@80d65ef is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
00:00:34,303 WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->21r35xoL]-HelperThread-#9][BasicResourcePool:894] Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@80d65ef is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
00:00:34,304 WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->21r35xoL]-HelperThread-#1][BasicResourcePool:894] Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@80d65ef is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.

Comment: How do you connect from Liferay to a MS SQL database?

Comment: I was going off directions I found on [Liferay's Fourm](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/17413513)

Comment: great so it should be possible, you have to do, in the Dockerfile, the same thing you do on a Linux

Comment: Well, I've followed those on a docker container, it didn't work.

Comment: Post the output from `docker logs container_id` and `docker events`

Comment: Yeah, it simply says it can't log into the database. The container can defiantly see the database, if I use an incorrect login, it fails saying the username/password is wrong.

Comment: And Docker events doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rechecking the errors, turned out there was an issue with SQL server's authentication. Solved via [this helpful post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/).

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should link the mysql container to the liferay container using the --link docker flag. The alias you provide to the mysql container should be *db_lep*.

```
docker run -d --name mysqldb --env-file=.crendentials mysql

docker run -d --link mysqldb:db_lep -p 8080:8080 {whatever the local name of the image is}
```

If you see the https://github.com/snasello/docker-liferay-6.2/blob/master/lep/portal-bd-MYSQL.properties the host for the database is  *db_lep*. If you provide your own properties file then you should change the alias to whatever is in your properties. If you are using localhost then instead of linking you should make the containers to share the same network(localhost).

Comment: I'm trying to use a non container database. On another machine in fact.